# Windows standard calulator replica in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, calculator, winforms

I tried my best to replicate, in style and functionality, the Windows standard calculator:

[image]

I would like to get some feedback on the efficiency and readability of my code as well as the approach i chose (for example the one of using the evaluate function on the expression textbox):

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace _2022_01_27
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool equals_last_pressed;
        double last_number_entry = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Add_to_entry(string digit)
        {
            if (tbox_entry.Text.Length <= 18)
            {
                tbox_entry.Text += digit;
                tbox_entry.Text = Convert.ToString(double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text));
            }
            equals_last_pressed = false;
        }

        static Double Evaluate(String expression)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            return Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute(expression, String.Empty));
        }

        private void btn_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("0");
        }

        private void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("1");
        }

        private void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("2");
        }

        private void btn_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("3");
        }

        private void btn_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("4");
        }

        private void btn_5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("5");
        }

        private void btn_6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("6");
        }

        private void btn_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("7");
        }

        private void btn_8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("8");
        }

        private void btn_9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add_to_entry("9");
        }

        private void btn_c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbox_entry.Text = "0";
            tbox_expression.Text = "";
            last_number_entry = 0;
        }

        private void btn_ce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbox_entry.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btn_backspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbox_entry.Text = tbox_entry.Text.Remove(tbox_entry.Text.Length - 1);
            if (tbox_entry.Text.Length == 0)
                tbox_entry.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btn_addition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            last_number_entry = double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text);
            if (equals_last_pressed == false)
                tbox_expression.Text += tbox_entry.Text;
            tbox_expression.Text = $"{Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text)} + ";
            tbox_entry.Text = "0";
            equals_last_pressed = false;
        }

        private void btn_subtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            last_number_entry = double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text);
            if (equals_last_pressed == false)
                tbox_expression.Text += tbox_entry.Text;
            tbox_expression.Text = $"{Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text)} - ";
            tbox_entry.Text = "0";
            equals_last_pressed = false;
        }

        private void btn_multiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            last_number_entry = double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text);
            if (equals_last_pressed == false)
                tbox_expression.Text += tbox_entry.Text;
            tbox_expression.Text = $"{Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text)} * ";
            tbox_entry.Text = "0";
            equals_last_pressed = false;
        }

        private void btn_division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            last_number_entry = double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text);
            if (equals_last_pressed == false)
                tbox_expression.Text += tbox_entry.Text;
            tbox_expression.Text = $"{Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text)} / ";
            tbox_entry.Text = "0";
            equals_last_pressed = false;
        }

        private void btn_sqrtx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbox_entry.Text = $"{Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text))}";
        }

        private void btn_x2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbox_entry.Text = $"{Math.Pow(double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text), 2)}";
        }

        private void btn_1dividex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbox_entry.Text == "0")
                return;
            tbox_entry.Text = $"{1 / double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text)}";
        }

        private void btn_equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            last_number_entry = double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text);
            if (equals_last_pressed == true)
                return;
            equals_last_pressed = true;
            tbox_expression.Text += $"{tbox_entry.Text}";
            tbox_entry.Text = Convert.ToString(Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text));
        }

        private void btn_period_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(char digit in tbox_entry.Text)
                if (digit == '.')
                    return;
            tbox_entry.Text += ".";
        }

        private void btn_changesign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbox_entry.Text.Contains("-"))
                tbox_entry.Text = tbox_entry.Text.Remove(0,1);
            else
                tbox_entry.Text = "-" + tbox_entry.Text;
        }

        private void btn_percentage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbox_entry.Text = Convert.ToString(last_number_entry / 100 * double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip: you can merge 10 handlers for digits into 1. `private void btn_digit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Add_to_entry((sender as Button).Text); }` and assign this handler to all 10 digit buttons. Other repetitive code can be eliminated in the same way.

Comment: @aepot thank you! that basically cut it in half

Comment: One more UI tip in a [project](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ItHQA4Z9tRpyqg). Note that window is sizable, check the behavior. UI only, no button handlers attached but you can improve it.

Comment: @aepot nice! i was trying to implement this but had no idea how, however i don't really get how i'm supposed to handle events and stuff if the controls aren't in the designer. I'll try to turn it into a version i can work with

Comment: @Tommaso What do mean by *efficiency*? Your code consists of mathematical operations, assignments and string concatenations. What kind of *efficiency* related problem can your program have?

Comment: @PeterCsala Any significant piece of code can be more or less efficient than another, i guess it's not a big deal here but some things can always be tweaked to run a little better/faster i assume

Comment: @Tommaso Are the `tbox_entry` and `tbox_expression` editable? Based on the shared code base their `Text` can be only changed by button clicks (or via keystroke if you have specified shortcuts). If that's the case then would it make sense to use labels instead?

Comment: @PeterCsala it would make sense apart from the fact that you can't copy text off labels (as far as i know)

Comment: @Tommaso Do you mean copying to the clipboard?

Comment: `button.Click += index switch { 0 => button1_click, 1 => button1_click ... };`

Comment: @PeterCsala yeah

Comment: @Tommaso By [double clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775252/13268855) will copy the content to the clipboard. That's the default behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCsala Should've guessed there was a way to make it do that. thanks!

Comment: `ToolStripMenu` with `Copy` item, readonly `TextBox`, many ways to copy/paste.

Comment: @Tommaso Did you find my post useful? If so please consider to upvote and/or accept as the answer.

Comment: @PeterCsala oh sorry, your answer definitely opened my mind to some things that i didn't even know you could do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [aepot](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/226545/aepot) has already mentioned a way how can you reduce the code of the `btn_{n}_Click` event handlers so, I will not address that problem here.

#### `Add_to_entry`

- I think the second `tbox_entry.Text` assignment is pointless
- This piece of code `double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text)` is being used in several places I suggest to introduce a helper method for that

```
private double GetEntryAsNumber()
    => double.Parse(tbox_entry.Text);
```

#### `Evaluate`

- According to my understanding you don't need to create a new `Table` each and every time when you call this method
- So, you can convert the `table` to a static member of the class

```
static System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
static double Evaluate(string expression)
    => Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute(expression, string.Empty));
```

#### `btn_c_Click` and `btn_ce_Click`

- This code `tbox_entry.Text = "0"` is being used in multiple places so you can define a helper method for this

```
private void SetEntryToZero()
    => tbox_entry.Text = "0";

private void btn_c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetEntryToZero();
    tbox_expression.Text = "";
    last_number_entry = 0;
}

private void btn_ce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => SetEntryToZero();
```

#### `btn_addition_Click` ... `btn_division_Click`

- As I can see their code are almost identical except that part which comes after the `Evaluate` call, so the common part can be extracted

```
private void btn_addition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => PrepareForTheSecondOperand("+");

private void btn_subtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => PrepareForTheSecondOperand("-");

private void btn_multiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => PrepareForTheSecondOperand("*");

private void btn_division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => PrepareForTheSecondOperand("/");
    
private void PrepareForTheSecondOperand(string operation)
{
    last_number_entry = GetEntryAsNumber();
    if (!equals_last_pressed)
        tbox_expression.Text += tbox_entry.Text;
    tbox_expression.Text = $"{Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text)} {operation} ";
    SetEntryToZero();
    equals_last_pressed = false;
}
```

- Instead of using the `== false` you can simply use the negation operator

#### `btn_sqrtx_Click` ... `btn_1dividex_Click`

- All three methods can be implemented as a one-liner

  - In case of `1dividex` you can use the conditional operator

```
private void btn_sqrtx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => tbox_entry.Text = $"{Math.Sqrt(GetEntryAsNumber())}";

private void btn_x2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => tbox_entry.Text = $"{Math.Pow(GetEntryAsNumber(), 2)}";
        
private void btn_1dividex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => tbox_entry.Text = tbox_entry.Text == "0" ? tbox_entry.Text : $"{1 / GetEntryAsNumber()}";
```

#### `btn_equals_Click`

- Two minor things:

  - You don't need to use string interpolation when you do the assignment for `tbox_expression.Text`
  - You don't need to use `Convert.ToString` static method, you can simply call the `ToString` instance method on the double

```
private void btn_equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    last_number_entry = GetEntryAsNumber();
    if (equals_last_pressed)
        return;
    equals_last_pressed = !equals_last_pressed;
    tbox_expression.Text += tbox_entry.Text;
    tbox_entry.Text = Evaluate(tbox_expression.Text).ToString();
}
```

#### `btn_period_Click`, `btn_changesign_Click` and `btn_percentage_Click`

- All three methods can be implemented as a one-liner

  - In case of `period` you can use Linq's `Any` to find a dot
  - In case of `changesign` you can use conditional operator

```
private void btn_period_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => tbox_entry.Text += tbox_entry.Text.ToCharArray().Any(c => c == '.') ? "" : ".";

private void btn_changesign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => tbox_entry.Text = tbox_entry.Text.Contains("-") ? tbox_entry.Text.Remove(0, 1): "-" + tbox_entry.Text;
        
private void btn_percentage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => tbox_entry.Text = Convert.ToString(last_number_entry / 100 * GetEntryAsNumber());
```